# Android Notification flash lights doesn't work

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to use Android Notification.

The notification vibrate and sound works, but the flashing lights don't, when the screen is off and neither when its on.

here's my code:

```
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
  notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
  notification.ledOnMS = 300;
  notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the phone plugged into a computer/charger? In my (user) experience, the "charging" steady light overrides all other light notifications on my devices (the notifications only flash when phone is not charging).

Comment: @Piskvor: is it possible that my android device don't support it? I have Galaxy S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device simply does not support this, most likely. Not all devices do.